# close Alert Dialog without using negative Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I created an AlertDialog, which will either refresh the activity (when *btnConfirm1* is pressed), or does nothing and simply closes down (when *btnDisconfirm1* is pressed). Everything is working apart from *btnDisconfirm1*. How can I close the dialog?

So apparently AlertDialog does not have a dismiss or cancel method, but is there another way without using negative buttons? The thing is, I created a layout file for this dialog and I don't know how to put a negative button in my xlm-file.

Or should I use a completely different approach apart from AlertDialog? Thanks!

```
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScoreScreen.this);

            View mView2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm_delete, null);

            Button btnConfirm1=(Button) mView2.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm1);
            Button btnDisconfirm1=(Button) mView2.findViewById(R.id.btnDisconfirm1);

            btnConfirm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    player1.setPlayerScore(0);
                    player2.setPlayerScore(0);
                    player3.setPlayerScore(0);
                    player4.setPlayerScore(0);

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            btnDisconfirm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                //WHAT DO I PUT HERE???
                }
            });
            mBuilder2.setView(mView2);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder2.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code snippet is somehow incomplete. Please add the lines where you actually create and show the AlertDialog

Comment: sorry, I just added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create the AlertDialog with
AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder2.create();

And secondly you can dismiss the dialog inside the OnClickListener with
mDialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

You can put this method in your Util class. and use callbacks

```
public interface OnDialogDismiss {
    void onPositiveClick();

    void onNegativeClick();
}
```

Modify it as your requirement.

```
public void showDialogForMultipleCallback(Context context, String title, String message, boolean cancellable, String neutralBbtn, String negativeBtn, String positiveBtn, final OnDialogDismiss onDialogDismiss) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder1.setTitle(title);
    builder1.setMessage(message);
    builder1.setCancelable(cancellable);
    if (neutralBbtn != null) {
        builder1.setNeutralButton(neutralBbtn, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (alert11 != null)
                    alert11.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (negativeBtn != null) {
        builder1.setNegativeButton(negativeBtn,
                new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if (alert11 != null)
                    alert11.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }
    if (positiveBtn != null) {
        builder1.setPositiveButton(positiveBtn, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                onDialogDismiss.onPositiveClick();
            }
        });
    }
    alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}
```